# Unset Virtual Field on the fly in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp

**My problem is:** when I do a **find all** for example, the $virtualFields are used too, but, I want choose when use them, or the possibility to disable in some cases.

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'sum_total_foods' => 'sum(OrderFood.quantity * OrderFood.price)',
    'sum_original_total_foods' => 'sum(OrderFood.quantity * OrderFood.original_price)',
    'sum_tax_amount' => 'sum((OrderFood.quantity * OrderFood.price) * OrderFood.tax)',
    'tax_amount' => '((OrderFood.quantity * OrderFood.original_price) * OrderFood.tax)',
    'total' => '(OrderFood.quantity * OrderFood.original_price)'
);
```

So, if a do:

```
$this->find('all');
```

CakePHP return *GROUP BY* error, and of course, I know why.

So, how can I disable `$virtualFields` on the fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use "fields" to specify the fields you want to use in this query (whitelisting).
Or you can use unset():

```
unset($this->virtualFields['total']);
```

etc

Careful: This would also remove those fields from all find() calls later in this very same request.
You might want to store them in a tmp attribute $virtualFieldsTmp to put them back into your virtual fields.

It would probably be wiser, though, to use/add virtual fields dynamically if they are not used on every find call:

```
public $availableVirtualFields = array(...);

// before your call
$this->virtualFields['x'] = $this->availableVirtualFields['x'];
...
$result = $this->find(...);
```

for example.

Comment: You might not believe it: In the end its still just PHP :D

Comment: Yes D: I'm just trying use CakePHP for do everything, never my 'incredible' knowledge, haha. Anyway, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

if you use it in your controller use it like this:

```
unset($this->YourModel->virtualFields['x']);
```

you need to access it through the model's method.